# Switch from E1 to Analog PSTN line on IP-PBX failure

Tags: asterisk, voip, gateway, pbx, pstn

I have two Asterisk servers,

1. E1(PRI) Gateway Asterisk 1.4 with E1(PRI) card
2. IP-PBX Asterisk 1.8 on VM Server

When my e1 gateway is failed (ex. shutdown, no power...), PSTN automatically switch to analog lines

but when my IP-PBX is failed I want to make the gateway to route the call back to the PSTN again and there switch the call to an analog line.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF. What precisely is the question you are asking?

Comment: which part of my question is not clear to you?

Comment: There is no actual question. You only describe your target design.

Comment: It seems that the question is:  **HOW to make the gateway to route the call back to the PSTN again and there switch the call to an analog line?**